# how to understand if vistor is human or bot?

Tags: web-crawler, bots, google-crawlers, visitors

when user visit my website I am storing a few of the information in my database. I want that with this information can I understand that user is human or bot and crawler?

this is the information

[image]

Comment: You should not be posting other peoples' potential IP addresses here.

Comment: those are fake from my local db

Comment: OK. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You can't tell from the request alone whether it's a human or a bot, which is why sites use CAPTCHA to force users to prove that they're human.